# Jquery problem slidedown

Tags: jquery, slidedown

Hallo i have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function animateIt() {
  $(".logo img").slideUp("slow")
}
animateIt();
</script>
```

When i use slideup. The image going away to the top. But i wil use the slidedown. But when i change slide up to slideDown("slow"). My .logo img is not working? What do i wrong?

Comment: Please post the associated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the dom to be ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function animateIt() {
  $(".logo img").slideUp("slow")
}

//wait for the onload event:
$(animateIt);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you running this script before the document is ready? have you tried replacing animateIt(); with

```
 $(animateIt);
```